# How to parse a MongoDB document to a Java class

Tags: java, json, mongodb, parsing

I'm using the `MongoDB` driver in Java.

Say I have a `MongoDB` document in the collection db.people:

`{"name":"Joe", "surname":"Blow", "age":20}`

and a Java class that looks something like

```
`public class Person {
   String name;
   String surname;
   int age;`

  `public void setPersonalInfo(String name, String surname, int age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.surname = surname;
     this.age = age;
   }
}`
```

How do I parse the information from my document into my class? Is there a way to do this by manipulating the document in the form of a `BasicDBObject`? I looked through the methods and couldn't make sense of how, as my first inclination was to use a method which returns an array of key value pairs (as far as I know, no such method exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jongo](http://jongo.org/) is your friend:

```
Person p = people.find("{age: {$gt: 18}}").as(Person.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Kundera is no longer maintained. Please use alternatives.

---

If you want to map MongoDB document directly with your Java object and **schema in mongoDB is fixed**, you can go for ORMs also. [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) is one of the good ORM for big data.

It supports CRUD & Query operation in a similar way like RDBMS. Find out more [here](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Kundera-with-MongoDB).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have executed a query, you typically iterate through the result.
For setting up queries and looking at a basic iteration, see the [MongoDB Java Driver Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/) and specifically the section **Using a Cursor to Get All the Documents**.

To parse the result instead of printing, look at the DBObject interface and the the [BSONObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/org/bson/BSONObject.html) methods it implements.  The *get* method is the one you can use to access fields.  Here is an example relative to your example document and Java class that you would use within an iterator block:

```
DBObject obj = cursor.next();
String name = obj.get("name");
//obtain other field values the same way
```